# Increasing voltage source frequency

Tags: frequency

I am trying to simulate a simple circuit using a simulation program like SPICE. In the beginning of the circuit I have a pulse train voltage source, later it is connected to a normal LPF. The voltage source frequency is set as 1 kHz, my question is how to increase this frequency?

The only options that I have is to change the time of the cycle and the voltage. If I set 1 ms and 5V, the frequency will be 1 kHz.

If I change the time to 0.5 ms, the result will be 5V for 0.5 ms and the rest is 0. (The second cycle will not start after 0.5 ms, so the frequency is same 1 kHz). Strange!

How do I increase the frequency of the voltage source?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve - forget about the detail - take a step back and ask yourself what you are ultimately trying to find out. I ask this because "AC analysis" sounds more like what you are needing.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this:
How to increase the frequency of the voltage source

Comment: How to change the frequency in spice?  That is some command line option for the voltage source.  What version of spice?  (I only really know LTspice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the frequency by making changes in either time or frequency. As you mentioned that you have changed time to 0.5ms, please make sure whether you have changed time period of one complete cycle (on time + off time). If your time period of one complete cycle is 0.5ms, your frequency should be 2khz, because frequency is number of cycles per second.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, frequency is not voltage dependent. Secondly, I'm not really sure what you want to achieve. What kind of waveform do you want to have (Pulse, Sinus...)?

If you want to have a pulse voltage output you can use

> PULSE(0 5 0 0 0 0.5m 1m 100)

which will generate a 5V pulse voltage with a frequency of 1kHz and 50% Duty Cycle. The pulse will be repeated 100 cycles.

Comment: I am using pulse voltage source, and want to increase the frequency of the pulses. I tried to increase it by minimize the pulse cycle time, but that dose not help.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your settings?